# Finding average ratings of a product that customers have not bought

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to find for each customer the products that they ahve not bought, and which of these products has the highest rating.

For example, in the tables below, John has bought items 1 and 2, but has not bought 3, 4, or 5. Products 3 and 5 have no rating, so they won't be included, but product 4 should be included because it is the highest rated item that John did not buy.

Here are my table structures with some sample data:

customer

```
id  | customer
----|---------
1   | john
2   | jenkins
3   | jane
4   | janet
```

product

```
id  | description
----|---------
1   | deoderant
2   | soap
3   | shampoo
4   | razor
5   | sponge
```

orders

```
customer_id  | product_id
-------------|---------
1            | 1
1            | 2
2            | 3
2            | 4
3            | 5
```

rate

```
customer_id  | product_id | rate
-------------|------------|-------
1            | 1          | 3
2            | 2          | 2
2            | 4          | 3
4            | 2          | 4
```

Comment: Do you want a list of all such products for all customers, or just for a specified customer?

Comment: For all products that customers have not bought, but rated.

Comment: Do you want a list of all such products for all customers, or just for a specified customer?

Comment: Yes, all the customers and all such products.

Comment: Is having a rating of >2 required, or is it the highest rating of items he has not bought regardless?

Comment: It is the highest rating he has not bought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started by writing a few subqueries before piecing them together. My personal advice is to always break down a problem into smaller bits before going after the whole solution.

For example, one thing I need to know is all of the products that each customer has not bought. I did so by cross-joining the customer and product table (to get all pairings) and removed pairs that already existed in the order table, like this:

```
-- Get all customer/product pairings where customer_product
-- does not exist in orders table
SELECT c.id, p.id
FROM customer c
CROSS JOIN product p
WHERE (c.id, p.id) NOT IN (SELECT * FROM orders)
ORDER BY c.id;
```

I also wrote a subquery to get the average rating of each product. This query will return null if the product has no ratings:

```
SELECT p.id, AVG(r.rate) AS averageRating
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN rate r ON r.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Now, I can include those two as subqueries and select the customers id, product id, and the rating of each product that they haven't bought:

```
SELECT t1.customerID, t1.productID, t2.averageRating
FROM(
  SELECT c.id AS customerID, p.id AS productID
  FROM customer c
  CROSS JOIN product p
  WHERE (c.id, p.id) NOT IN (SELECT * FROM orders)
  ORDER BY c.id) t1
JOIN(
  SELECT p.id AS productID, AVG(r.rate) AS averageRating
  FROM product p
  LEFT JOIN rate r ON r.product_id = p.id
  GROUP BY p.id) t2 ON t2.productID = t1.productID;
```

That was the hardest part. The only thing left to do is some aggregation to get the largest rating for each customer from items they haven't bought, and then join that aggregation query with the query above on the condition that the max rating matches the average rating. So, here is the monstrous query that I've put together:

```
SELECT t1.customerID, t1.productID, t1.averageRating
FROM(
  SELECT t1.customerID, t1.productID, t2.averageRating
  FROM(
    SELECT c.id AS customerID, p.id AS productID
    FROM customer c
    CROSS JOIN product p
    WHERE (c.id, p.id) NOT IN (SELECT * FROM orders)
    ORDER BY c.id) t1
  JOIN(
    SELECT p.id AS productID, AVG(r.rate) AS averageRating
    FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN rate r ON r.product_id = p.id
    GROUP BY p.id) t2 ON t2.productID = t1.productID) t1
JOIN(
  SELECT t1.customerID, MAX(t2.averageRating) AS maxRating
  FROM(
    SELECT c.id AS customerID, p.id AS productID
    FROM customer c
    CROSS JOIN product p
    WHERE (c.id, p.id) NOT IN (SELECT * FROM orders)
    ORDER BY c.id) t1
  JOIN(
    SELECT p.id AS productID, AVG(r.rate) AS averageRating
    FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN rate r ON r.product_id = p.id
    GROUP BY p.id) t2 ON t2.productID = t1.productID
  GROUP BY t1.customerID) t2 ON t2.customerID = t1.customerID AND t2.maxRating = t1.averageRating
ORDER BY t1.customerID;
```

And here is a snapshot of the results from MySQL workbench:
[image]

An important thing to note is that I did not eliminate ties. So, for example, customer 2 has not bought products 1 or 2 and they have the same rating, so two rows are returned.

I tested in MySQL because SQL Fiddle wasn't working, but I got that to work so here is a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f3b7/19) example if you prefer that.

Comment: Trying to test this but I keep getting the error message stating "Operand should contain 2 columns".

Comment: @Dino At what line? Does your real orders table have more than two columns? That will screw up my subquery where I wrote select * from orders. You may need to change that to select cust, product from orders.

Comment: Ah orders has the price on it as well, let me check that. I did change it too include customer_id and product_id and it worked since I am not interested in the price.

Comment: I didn't scrutinise the results. Will do that in the morning as I'm very tired now.

Comment: I get the same results, but the query is very very big. I did a similar thing where I did the search for customers that did not order anything and then I did a query on average rates of the products separately but did not know how to join them in to one query.

Comment: How does the query run though? I can try to trim it down a bit if it's too slow?

Comment: It seems to run fine, but the data is on the small side. So shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Dino alright. Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it works for you. Otherwise, post whatever solution you use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this for one customer, just use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select c.*, r.*
from customers c cross join
     (select r.product_id, avg(rating) avgr
      from rating r
      group by r.product_id
     ) r left join
     orders o
     on o.customer_id = c.customer_id and
        o.product_id = r.product_id 
where c.customer_id = @customerid and o.product_id is null
order by r.avgr desc
limit 1;
```

If you want it for all customers at once, it is a bit more complicated.  One way is with the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select c.*,
       substring_index(group_concat(r.product_id order by avgr desc), ',', 1) as product_id
from customers c cross join
     (select r.product_id, avg(rating) avgr
      from rating r
      group by r.product_id
     ) r left join
     orders o
     on o.customer_id = c.customer_id and
        o.product_id = r.product_id 
where c.customer_id = @customerid and o.product_id is null
group by c.customer_id;
```

Comment: I think you've omitted `LEFT JOIN` before naming the `orders` table in your `from` clauses.  And your second query probably shouldn't still have a filter on `c.customer_id` in the `where` clause?

Comment: @eggyal is right, you are missing the left join keyword. However, I tested this out in workbench using that left join and this worked out great.

Comment: When I do a left join before orders I get no results :(

Comment: @Dino . . . Is it possible to set up a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: @GordonLinoff here is the [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f3b7/9) I think I did it right but not sure. (EDIT - I just tested it and it seems to work)

Comment: @dino . . . Remove `c.customer_id = @customerid `.  I thought you wanted the results for one customer.